# webpack error in Angular2 ng-dygraph /index.ts unexpected character '@'

Tags: angular, macos, webpack, asp.net-core, dygraphs

I am working with [ng-dygraph](https://github.com/mpx200/ng-dygraphs) in my aspnet core + Angular2 application.

in my project folder say sohaib/myproject I am running command webpack --config webpack.vendor.js , dygraphs are working fine on windows machine but are throwing error on mac saying " myproject/node_modules/ng-dygraphs/index.ts Unexpected '@' (5:0) ". you can see the image below if needed (error details on mac) 
[image]

I had different version of npm and node on windows and mac but then I made them alike i.e. npm version: 3.10.10, node version: v6.11.0 but still I'm facing same error in webpack command.

Error details can be viewed in image. What can be the possible fix for this particular problem.

Is there any OS things stopping it or I'm missing something?
All I need is the working code on all development machines targeting same repository.

Comment: Don’t post screenshots of text. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: Hey I have added all the information in text form too, screenshot is just to  add value as you can see, did I not use the add image option the way it was supposed to be used?